# Create key/value-­‐array pairs Scala/Spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark, bigdata

How can I create key/value-array pair in Scala. By this I mean in place of value I need an array.

```
val newRdd1 = rdd1.flatMap(x=>x.split(" "))
   .map({case (key, Array(String)) => Array(String) })
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking to make sure you provide all the information needed for people to be able to help. Specifically - what have you tried? Where are you stuck? Have you searched online for answers?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

You can achieve it using map(), it is similar in either plain scala program or Scala-in-SparkContext.

Example, you have a list of strings:

```
var sRec = List("key1,a1,a2,a3", "key2,b1,b2,b3", "key3,c1,c2,c3")
```

You can split it & convert to key/value(array of strings) assuming key is in 0th position, using:

```
sRec.map(x => (x.split(",")(0), Array(x.split(",")(1), x.split(",")(2), x.split(",")(3)))).
        foreach(println)

(key1,[Ljava.lang.String;@7a81197d)
(key2,[Ljava.lang.String;@5ca881b5)
(key3,[Ljava.lang.String;@24d46ca6)
```

If you want to read a particular array element by key:

```
sRec.map(x => (x.split(",")(0),Array(x.split(",")(1), x.split(",")(2), x.split(",")(3)))).
        map(x => (x._1, x._2(0))).foreach(println)
```

Output:

```
(key1,a1)
(key2,b1)
(key3,c1)
```